# SAMBA copy file without properties: the file has properties that can't be copied to new location

Tags: files, permissions, windows, samba, download

From `Windows 10` (enterprise) copying a file that has only been  **downloaded** from internet will I get a windows popup saying:

> *Are you sure you want to copy this file without it's properties?*
>
> *The file xxxx has properties that can't be copied to the new location*

**I've noticed this is with only files that are downloaded** and it will be for any file; for any locally created file (click new text file or create an excel file) that will copy to my linux samba share without problem.  But for **any** file it seems that I've downloaded (for example release_notes.pdf) that will have this warning prior to copy.

What causes this?  What file properties are different for a downloaded file versus a locally created one?

What file properties am I missing out on, will it ever become a problem?

I also do not remember this being so prevalent when we were `Windows 7`, now with win10 it is with any downloaded file.

Answer (score 1):

Windows flags file downloaded from the internet as potentially dangerous. For this purpose it uses a feature of NTFS called Alternative Data Stream, or Fork. Samba detects the flag, but cannot copy the alternative data stream, most likely because the destination file system does not support forks. [See Wikipedia's article on NTFS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_(ADS))